# Programmatically creating triggers fails sometimes

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to set lots of triggers in my google spreadsheet to update some sheets.

To avoid a painful task, i've set manually one trigger which programmatically set the others needed, in function of the task (batch processing etc...)

Well, here's my function called to create those triggers

```
function createTriggers(sheet, hour){
  var nbTrigger = sheet.getLastColumn() * sheet.getLastRow() / 1100 + 1 ;
  var buffHour = new Date().getHours();
  var min = new Date().getMinutes()+10;
  if(min >=60){
    min = min % 60;
    buffHour++;
    if(buffHour>=24){
      buffHour = buffHour % 24;
    }
  }
  //Browser.msgBox(buffHour+"h"+min);
  var ok = false;
  var cpt = 0;
  do {
    try {
     ScriptApp.newTrigger("triggered").timeBased().atHour(new Date().getHours()).nearMinute(Math.abs(1)).everyDays(1).create();
      ok = true;
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
      cpt++;
    } 
  }while(!ok && cpt<10);

  if(cpt>10){
    throw "Was unable to create a trigger...";
  }

  for(var i = 0; i<nbTrigger; i++){
    ok = false;
    cpt = 0;
    do {
      try {
        var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("update").timeBased().atHour(buffHour).nearMinute(Math.abs(min)).everyDays(1).create();
        ok = true;
      } catch(e) {
        Logger.log(e);
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
        cpt++;
      }
    } while(!ok && cpt<10);

    if(cpt>10){
      throw "Was unable to create a trigger...";
    }

    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    min +=7;
    if(min >= 60){
      buffHour++;
      min = 0;
      if(buffHour == 24){
        buffHour = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've to put triggers's creations into a try catch block because of that :

```
Wed May 09 13:36:41 PDT 2012 INFO: Exception: Invalid value -2 for field MINUTE, should be between [Range:0, 59]
Wed May 09 13:36:42 PDT 2012 INFO: Exception: Invalid value -8 for field MINUTE, should be between [Range:0, 59]
Wed May 09 13:36:43 PDT 2012 INFO: Exception: Invalid value -7 for field MINUTE, should be between [Range:0, 59]
Wed May 09 13:36:44 PDT 2012 INFO: Exception: Invalid value -7 for field MINUTE, should be between [Range:0, 59]
```

Where does it come from ?? Why it happens not every time ?? What could I do to avoid this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for raising this issue - it's a bug in the ClockTriggerBuilder.nearMinute() method. I've raised it in the issue tracker for you: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1320. If you star it, you'll be updated of the progress on it.

As a workaround in the meantime, pass minute values to the nearMinute() method that are between 8 and 52, inclusive.